# How to wrap groups of li tags inside ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu that contains a bunch of li tags and some of them having this class "sub-item" and I want to group those li tags inside a ul so my navigation which is like this :

```
<ul class='main-menu'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Community</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_About Me</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Blog</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">DropDown </a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Will become like this :

```
<ul id='main-menu'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Community</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_About Me</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    <li><a href="#">DropDown </a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">_Sub Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my attempt to do this but unfortunately it didn't worked :

```
$('.main-menu li a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    content = $this.text();

  if (content.indexOf('_') != -1) {
    $this.parent('li').addClass('sub-item');
  }

});
$('.sub-item').wrapAll('<ul class="sub-menu"></ul>');
```

Here is a JsFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hc05fhxr/1/

Comment: Why not have it like that in the first place? Is there a particular reason why you need to change it from what is there to having it all wrapped?

Comment: There's no grouping convention for `<li>`. If you want  a sub-list, the inner `<ul>` should go *inside* an `<li>`.

Comment: Again, why not just have it the way you want it in the first place? like so: https://jsfiddle.net/hc05fhxr/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c0m8nv2s/2/

Comment: @Toiletduck The reason why is because I can't edit the output so I had to figure out something to edit the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired output given in your question is invalid as [li](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li) can't have `ul` as its content.

I possible alternate is to add the new `ul` as a descendant of the previous anchor

```js
$('li:not(.sub-item)').each(function() {
  var $li = $(this),
    $subs = $li.nextUntil(':not(.sub-item)');
  if ($subs.length) {
    $('<ul />', {
      'class': 'sub-menu'
    }).html($subs).appendTo($li);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='main-menu'>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Community</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">DropDown </a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
  <li class='sub-item'><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination prev() and after()

```
$('.main-menu li').each(function(index, el) {
  var el = $(el);

    if (!el.hasClass("sub-item"))    {
        el.after($("<ul></ul>"));
    } else {
        el.prev("ul").append(el);
    }
});
$('.main-menu ul:empty').remove()
```

Here is your fiddle updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/hc05fhxr/3/